# Max and Min row numbers from single cte code block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

```
;with cte1 as
(  select  id,
row_number() over (partition by pk,pp,sn order by id asc)
as rn
from mqms_production
) select * into #M from cte1 where rn=1
```

With the above, I get all the rows with rn=1 but  I also want to copy to another table all the rows with max rn for a given partition pk,pp, sn.

Is it possibleto do it without having to write the cte block again with 
    (partition by pk,pp,sn order by id DESC)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just add another window function based expression there with reverse sort order and get the top rows on both of them

```
with cte1 as (
    select  id,
        row_number() over (partition by pk,pp,sn order by id asc) as rn1,
        row_number() over (partition by pk,pp,sn order by id desc) as rn2
    from mqms_production
)
select * from cte1 
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1;
```

Comment: This will return ID into the result set twice, unless it has only one row.  However, if you only filter to rn1 = 1, there will only be a single row and rn2 will have the max value of rn.

Comment: @WesH - No and that's not the question.